# Problems with curl and hebrew

Tags: php, curl, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to connect to a remote webpage with curl.

```
$ch = curl_init(API_URL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response = trim(curl_exec($ch));
```

`$params="SomeVariable=תפוח";`

It doesn't work, the remote server probably doesn't get the request the way I wanted.
I sniffed with WireShark and I got this: `SomeVariable=\327\252\327\244\327\225\327\227`.
I wasn't able to find out what exactly is that string.

What do you think?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work - what does `curl_error()` say? What response are you expecting? (The data in `someVariable` should probably be URL encoded, though: http://php.net/urlencode)

Comment: @Pekka The response that I'm getting from the server is not what I expect for non-english characters.
I know for sure that the server does support non-english characters, therefore I'm sure that the problem is with my code.

Comment: Do `urlencode()` the data and see if that helps

Comment: No prob. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URLencode your post data.

```
$data = urlencode("תפוח");
$params = "someVariable=".$data;
```